# BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT not finding setter method

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I am trying to apply the BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT to class as shown below:

```
class XY {
private:
    std::string x; // lhs
    std::list<std::list<std::string>> y;

public:
    std::list<std::list<std::string>> const &getY() const {
        return y;
    }

    void setY(std::list<std::list<std::string>> const &y) {
        this->y = y;
    }

    std::string const &getX() const { return x; }

    void setX(std::string const &x) { this->x = x; }
};
```

However, I am getting the following error, I can't quite figure out what is wrong.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: error: no matching function for call to ‘Rule::setY(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’
                        (std::list<std::list<std::string>> const&, std::list<std::list<std::string>> const&, obj.getY(), obj.setY(val))
                                                                                                                         ^
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: note: candidate: void Rule::setY(const std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&)
     void setY(std::list<std::list<std::string>> const &y) {
```

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion you might be writing a parser. I have had bad luck using ADAPT_ADT with Spirit Qi in the past. Basically, I ran into UB due to the member proxies all the time. I hope it's fixed by now but I wouldn't personally bet on it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't sow how you used it. However, when I try it there is no problem:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TYxhEE)**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/copy.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
using namespace std::string_literals;
using Lists = std::list<std::list<std::string> >;

class XY {
  private:
    std::string x;
    Lists y;

  public:
    void setY(Lists       const& y) { this->y = y; }
    void setX(std::string const& x) { this->x = x; }

    [[nodiscard]] Lists       const& getY() const { return y; }
    [[nodiscard]] std::string const& getX() const { return x; }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT(XY,
        (obj.getX(), obj.setX(val))
        (obj.getY(), obj.setY(val))
    )

int main() {
    XY test;
    boost::fusion::copy(
        std::make_tuple("hello", Lists { {"world"s, "bye"s}, {"world"s} }),
        test);

    fmt::print("{}\n{}\n",
            test.getX(),
            test.getY());
}
```

Prints

```
hello
{{"world", "bye"}, {"world"}}
```

Comment: My bad

`
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT(XY,
                       (std::list<std::list<std::string>> const&,std::list<std::list<std::string>> const&, obj.getY(), obj.setY(val))
                       (std::string const&, std::string const&, obj.getX(), obj.setX(val)) )
`
I think the order of the attributes in the ADAPT_ADT should match the arrangement in the class definition. When I changed the order, it worked.

Comment: The order cannot be relevant. If anything, it could be the template arguments because you're using the pre-C++11 form with the types specified

Comment: Okay. Changing the syntax to match yours still flags the error. But since it is converting the struct to fusion sequence shouldn't the order matter?

Comment: Yes it shouldn't. It's not "converting" - it's _adapting_. You are describing the property accessors. You can do so in any order. [In fact, you can do so in different orders https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct_named.html)

Comment: that's strange because even when I switch them in your solution above, the compiler flags errors.